Count the number of whitespaces with TreeSitter
I am trying to figure out if a javascript file is minified or not and I was thinking if we could use TreeSitter for that purpose. I mean we parse the file with the help of TreeSitter parser, get the tokens and count the number of whitespaces etc with the help of TreeSitter api's. Based on the data collected, take a decision whether the file is minified or not.
Do you think we could acheive with TreeSitter?
I have read a little bit about SpiderMoney and TreeSitter. TreeSitter looks much simpler to me but only an expert with the internal details of the TreeSitter would be able to put some light on this. Thank you.

A significantly simpler approach would be to minify the file with the most popular minifiers, and check whether any of them leaves the file unchanged.
